# How to determine odd number from a displayed sequence in C?

Tags: c

I would like to determine the odd numbers from a given sequence of numbers. After determining,I want to display those odd numbers.

Can you help me?
I can only use loops,if-elseif-else,swtich,break and continue. Anything beyond the said lessons are not allowed. 
Thank you.
P.S
I am sorry if I cannot provide the code. I want to code it on my own.I just need some ideas from you.

Comment: % plus 14 more characters to make the comment postable

Comment: Go through the sequence with a loop. Check for odd number and display with if-elseif-else. Sorry I cannot provide the code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Loop through the array(sequence) element by element
2. If an `array_element%2` is one, display the number.(`%` is the modulus operator and gets the remainder of the division of its operands)

Now just convert the above steps into code.